# R: Melt with data.table into two columns

Tags: r, data.table, melt

I would like to convert a data.table from wide to long format.
A "normal" melt works fine, but I would like to melt my data into two different columns.

I found information about this here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html (Point 3)

I tried this with my code but somehow it is not working and until now I could not figure out the problem.
It would be great if you could explain me the mistake in the following example.

Thanks

```
#Create fake data
a = c("l1","l2","l2","l3")
b = c(10, 10, 20, 10)
c = c(30, 30, 30, 30)
d = c(40.2, 32.1, 24.1, 33.0)
e = c(1,2,3,4)
f = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)
colnames(df) <- c("fac_a", "fac_b", "fac_c", "m1", "m2.1", "m2.2")

#install.packages("data.table")
require(data.table)
TB <- setDT(df)

#Standard melt - works
TB.m1 = melt(TB, id.vars = c("fac_a", "fac_b", "fac_c"), measure.vars = c(4:ncol(TB)))

#Melt into two columns
colA = paste("m1", 4, sep = "")
colB = paste("m2", 5:ncol(TB), sep = "")
DT = melt(TB, measure = list(colA, colB), value.name = c("a", "b"))
#Not working, error: Error in melt.data.table(TB, measure = list(colA, colB), value.name = c("a",  : One or more values in 'measure.vars' is invalid.
```

Comment: your `paste` is wrong. You have to change it into `paste0("m1")` and `paste0("m2.", 1:2)`

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve and what colA and colB should do without any assignment.

Comment: Thx, the solution from Felipe works! The goal was to split different measurements into different columns.